# Loading packages by reading text file in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I would like to know how to load packages reading a text file in shiny. I have put the text file containing package list in `www` directory of the shiny application. The application loads the packages and works fine locally, however when I deploy it on shiny server, it does not load the packages and gives `error of not finding the packages`.

> > Error in library(simpleaffy) : there is no package called ‘simpleaffy’

The example code is below.

**server.R**

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  withProgress(message = "Please wait", value = 0, expr = {
    for (i in 1:15) {
      source(textConnection(readLines("www/packages.txt", warn = FALSE)[i]))
      incProgress(amount = 1/15, detail = paste0("Loading package ", i, "/15"))
      Sys.sleep(time = 0.1)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: What is the exact `Error` message?

Comment: @Malvina_a Kindly follow the edit above

Comment: Great, How many packages do you read in? only `simpleaffy`?

Comment: Why are you loading the packages on the client side in the first place?

Comment: @Malvina_a Nearly 15 packages, `simpleaffy` is the first packages in the list, so get error  of  that

Comment: @PorkChop Actually the packages were outside `shinyServer()`, but the application takes some time to load, so to have a feel that application is loading packages, I put inside `shinyServer()` with progress message